# How can I improve performance of Sudoku solver?

Tags: python, performance

I can't improve the performance of the following Sudoku Solver code. I know there are 3 loops here and they probably cause slow performance but I can't find a better/more efficient way. "board" is mutated with every iteration of recursion - if there are no zeros left, I just need to exit the recursion.

I tried to isolate "board" from mutation but it hasn't changed the performance. I also tried to use list comprehension for the top 2 "for" loops (i.e. only loop through rows and columns with zeros), tried to find coordinates of all zeros, and then use a single loop to go through them - hasn't helped.

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here with recursion - any advice or recommendation on how to make the solution faster?

```
def box(board,row,column):
    start_col = column - (column % 3)
    finish_col = start_col + 3
    start_row = row - (row % 3)
    finish_row = start_row + 3
    return [y for x in board[start_row:finish_row] for y in x[start_col:finish_col]]

def possible_values(board,row,column):
    values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    col_values = [v[column] for v in board]
    row_values = board[row]
    box_values = box(board, row, column)
    return (values - set(row_values + col_values + box_values))

def solve(board, i_row = 0, i_col = 0):
    for rn in range(i_row,len(board)):
        if rn != i_row: i_col = 0
        for cn in range(i_col,len(board)):
            if board[rn][cn] == 0:
                options = possible_values(board, rn, cn)
                for board[rn][cn] in options:
                    if solve(board, rn, cn): 
                        return board
                    board[rn][cn] = 0
                #if no options left for the cell, go to previous cell and try next option
                return False
    #if no zeros left on the board, problem is solved
    return True

problem = [
            [9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0],
            [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
            [4, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 8],
            [0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
            [0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7]
        ]

solve(problem)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Maybe also this question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It won't work that way - you use backtracking and it's exponential in terms of time complexity. Efficient sudoku solver is something you probably don't want to write at this point.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: I recommend to stick with a variant of filling fields with just one possible value in loop, it's something doable.

Comment: @kosciej16 the task says to use backtracking, and apparently, some people got the approach working twice faster somehow. Sorry, I didn't understand your suggestion about one possible value - is it about the 3rd loop (options)? How would it make it faster?

Comment: You can start with such rn/cn that `len(possible_values)` is smallest. It should help.

Comment: @kosciej16 ah, got it, thanks for the hint. I'll try it but it will be a completely different solution. Do you think there is something that can be optimised in the current implementation?

Comment: I'd recommend this beautiful [article by Peter Norvig](https://norvig.com/sudoku.html). Apart from implementing an efficient solver, it is a very clear introduction to Constraint Propagation techniques

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, I added MRE and posted the question in codereview as well

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Three things you can do to speed this up:

- Maintain additional state using arrays of integers to keep track of row, col, and box candidates (or equivalently values already used) so that finding possible values is just `possible_values = row_candidates[row] & col_candidates[col] & box_candidates[box]`. This is a constant factors thing that will change very little in your approach.
- As kosciej16 suggested use the min-remaining-values heuristic for selecting which cell to fill next. This will turn your algorithm into crypto-[DPLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm), giving you early conflict detection (cells with 0 candiates), constraint propagation (cells with 1 candidate), and a lower effective branching factor for the rest.
- Add logic to detect hidden singles (like the Norvig solver does). This will make your solver a little slower for the simplest puzzles, but it will make a huge difference for puzzles where hidden singles are important (like 17 clue puzzles).

Answer (score 0):

A result that worked at the end thanks to 53x15 and kosciej16. Not ideal or most optimal but passes the required performance test:

```
def solve(board, i_row = 0, i_col = 0):
    cells_to_solve = [((rn, cn), possible_values(board,rn,cn)) for rn in range(len(board)) for cn in range(len(board)) if board[rn][cn] == 0]
    if not cells_to_solve: return True

    min_n_of_values = min([len(x[1]) for x in cells_to_solve])
    if min_n_of_values == 0: return False

    best_cells_to_try = [((rn,cn),options) for ((rn,cn),options) in cells_to_solve if len(options) == min_n_of_values]

    for ((rn,cn),options) in best_cells_to_try:
        for board[rn][cn] in options:
            if solve(board, rn, cn): 
                return board
            board[rn][cn] = 0
        return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).